# Hide Native AdView if not loaded

Tags: android, native-ads

What i am trying to achieve is hide my Ad view if it is not loaded due to internet or no ad from server.

**MainActivity.java**

```
NativeExpressAdView nativeView =
            (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.natvie_ad);
    nativeView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("testDeviceID").build());
```

**Layout**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/moreView"
        android:id="@+id/natvie_ad"
        ads:adSize="300x80"
        ads:adUnitId="adUnitID"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

first set the visibility to gone in your xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/moreView"
    android:id="@+id/natvie_ad"
    ads:adSize="300x80"
    ads:adUnitId="adUnitID"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

then in your java code set an AdListener like this

```
NativeExpressAdView nativeView =
        (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.natvie_ad);
nativeView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("testDeviceID").build());

nativeView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

I hope that help :)